# Is it possible to download excel or CSV report file in selenium grid at desire location?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-grid

I am trying to download `excel` and `CSV` report file in `Selenium Grid` but can't able to see downloaded file at desire location.

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(); 
profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",false);
String path=System.getProperty("user.dir");
System.out.println(path);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir",path);
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/msword,application/x-rar-compressed," + "application/octet-stream,application/csv,text/csv");
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
cap.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
cap.setBrowserName("firefox");
cap.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("GRID_URL"),cap);
    //WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver(profile);                          
driver.get("http://www.winzip.com/landing/open-rar-file.html");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='lan_img']")).click();
System.out.println("File downloaded at location::"+path);
```

Answer (score 0):

The file is being downloaded in the node machine to which the Grid Hub routed your test and NOT to your local machine [ This becomes complicated when your test is being triggered from a different machine and the node is running on a different machine ]

Ideally speaking you should not be automating tests that involve file downloads.
If its an absolute must, then I would suggest that you extract out the cookies from your web session and then rely on http client to download the file programmatically (wherein selenium is not involved).

I would suggest that you please take a look at [this](http://ardesco.lazerycode.com/index.php/2012/07/how-to-download-files-with-selenium-and-why-you-shouldnt/) in-depth blog post by Mark Collins, wherein he elaborately talks about selenium and file downloads, the pros and cons and what alternatives can be used.

Some of the helpers he talks about in his blog are also available on [github](https://github.com/Ardesco/Powder-Monkey).